# CROSS JOIN in DB2 v8 for z/OS

Tags: linq, db2, entity-framework-5, mainframe

I am using IBM DB2 v8 (New-Function mode) and I am using Entity Framework 5.0.0
I have a LINQ query which executes perfectly in my environment, but it is not working at another environment. I tried to extract the SQL query generated for that LINQ query by debugging the code. I tried to execute that SQL in my environment (DB2 DB v9.1 and DB2 driver 10.5), it worked well. For the same query it did not work in my another environment: DB2 DB v8 (New-Function mode) and DB2 driver 9.7. It gave an error for `"CROSS" JOIN`. As I am using LINQ, the query is an automatically generated one, which I cannot change. I want to make that run in my second environment also. Below I have given my sample query. Please let me know if there is any way to solve this ?

```
SELECT t1.MyName, t2.MySalary
FROM Employee t1 CROSS JOIN Salary t2
```

I got the following Error :

> ILLEGAL SYMBOL "CROSS". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE:.
>   SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601

Answer (score 0):

V8 does not support the `CROSS JOIN` clause. From the manuals:

V8: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_8.2.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000875.htm

**joined-table**

```
>>-+-table-reference--+-----------+--JOIN--table-reference--ON--join-condition-+-><
   |                  '-| outer |-'                                            |
   '-(--joined-table--)--------------------------------------------------------'
```

V9.5: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000875.html

**joined-table**

```
>>-+-table-reference--+-----------+--JOIN--table-reference--ON--join-condition-+-><
   |                  '-| outer |-'                                            |   
   +-table-reference--CROSS JOIN--table-reference------------------------------+   
   '-(--joined-table--)--------------------------------------------------------'
```

Note the new `CROSS JOIN` clause in newer releases. On a side note, V8 is no longer supported, you should really switch to a newer release ;-)

HTH.

Comment: The OP apparently uses DB2 for z/OS in production, where the `CROSS JOIN` syntax was not available until version 10. Why would one test the application on an entirely different platform, is beyond me.

Comment: Ah, sry, missed the z/OS part of the question. My links are for LUW. Thanks for the comment!